# Call a javascript function on button click in jquery mobile application

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

can anyone tell me how to call a javascript function on button click in jquery mobile application . I am using jquery mobile in my mvc application.
I want to call a jquery function on focus of a textbox.
I can not make the call in the traditional way

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Did you try,

```
$("#inputboxid").focus(function(){

});
```

// this is a tranditional way in jquery :)